# Render razor page with RazorViewToStringRenderer and ServiceStack

Tags: macos, razor, .net-core, servicestack

I'm trying to render a razor page to send it as an email template. I'm adding the views on a Razor library and trying to render these from a ServiceStack project using this [class](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/master/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs). I'm getting the following error:

```
Application startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to find view '/Test.cshtml'. The following locations were searched:
/Test.cshtml)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find view '/Test.cshtml'. The following locations were searched:
/Test.cshtml
 at web.RazorTemplates.RazorViewToStringRenderer.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, String viewName) in /Users/herber/Documents/repos/tests/web/web.RazorTemplates/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs:line 86
 at web.RazorTemplates.RazorViewToStringRenderer.RenderViewToStringAsync[TModel](String viewName, TModel model) in /Users/herber/Documents/repos/tests/web/web.RazorTemplates/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs:line 39
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at web.AppHost.Configure(Container container) in /Users/herber/Documents/repos/tests/ss-razor-library/web/web/Startup.cs:line 65
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 282
at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.UseServiceStack(IApplicationBuilder app, AppHostBase appHost) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 333
at web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /Users/herber/Documents/repos/tests/ss-razor-library/web/web/Startup.cs:line 44
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
    crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost[6]
    Application startup exception
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to find view '/Test.cshtml'. The following locations were searched:
    /Test.cshtml)
    ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find view '/Test.cshtml'. The following locations were searched:
    /Test.cshtml
```

The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/herbergt/ss-razor-library/tree/master/web). Just for testing purpose I'm trying to render the template form the app [Startup](https://github.com/herbergt/ss-razor-library/blob/master/web/web/Startup.cs#L65) class.

I can render the template from a regular .net core app but not from a ServiceStack app. The repo for a working example on a regular .net core app can be found [here](https://github.com/herbergt/ss-razor-library/tree/master/RazorTest). The render is performed on [index page](https://github.com/herbergt/ss-razor-library/blob/master/RazorTest/RazorTest/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs#L26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples are not the same, you're rendering it from an MVC Controller:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IRazorViewToStringRenderer _razorRenderer;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IRazorViewToStringRenderer razorRenderer)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _razorRenderer = razorRenderer;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var body =  _razorRenderer.RenderViewToStringAsync("/Test.cshtml",new TestModel{Message = "World"}).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }
}
```

vs On Startup before the App has been initialized:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig
    {
        DefaultRedirectPath = "/metadata",
        DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false)
    });

    var razorRenderer = container.Resolve<IRazorViewToStringRenderer>();
    var body =  razorRenderer.RenderViewToStringAsync("/Test.cshtml",new TestModel()).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

Since you're trying to use MVC's Razor implementation instead of [ServiceStack.Razor](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor) you should be rendering it inside an MVC Controller or Razor page, not a ServiceStack AppHost or Service which has its own Razor implementation for usage in ServiceStack Services that uses its own [stand-alone Razor APIs](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/loading-razor-views-programmtically-in-netcore/8210/5?u=mythz). If you're interested in using **ServiceStack.Razor** refer to the [razor](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/razor) project template for a valid configuration.

Although since it's simpler, cleaner & more flexible than Razor & actually designed to be used in a [stand-alone Sandbox](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sandbox), you should also consider ServiceStack [#Script](https://sharpscript.net/) for rendering stand-alone templates, here's a [rendering Email template example](https://sharpscript.net/usecases/email-templates).

Comment: Thank for your response @mythz. I will try the with #Script looks amazing. I also need to manage multiple languages, there is some way to do it with resource files in #Script?

Comment: @herbergt No there’s no resource files support, I never use the built in Lang resources support & have historically just coded text substitution manually. Normally by calling methods with the default English text (+ some pluralized context) that can be swapped out when the phrase was exists in target lang.

Comment: Thanks @mythz, we have used #Script and works perfectly for the email templates without the need of mvc dependencies.